# When I run a python script in VS Code I always get command text that looks to be the command it uses to execute the script. How can I get rid of it?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am on Windows 10.  VSCode ver: 1.48.1 (user install).  I have reinstalled Code and only have the Python extension installed.

### Whether I set the cmd shell, power shell, debug console, and whether I use Ctrl-F5 or a menu pic, I always get the below printout before I get any print statements from the actual Python script.  My Python executes, but it bothers me (I didn't use to get this), and I cannot figure out how to remove it.  If this behavior is some kind of "new normal" I'm not aware of, apologies up front...

PS C:\Users\uname\Documents\bin\python\classes>  & 'C:\Python38-32\python.exe' 'c:\Users\uname.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.8.103604\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\launcher' '60268' '--' 'c:\Users\uname\Documents\bin\python\classes\myscript.py'

Comment: this is to attach VSC to the python debugger. Run your python script without debugger, see `Run` menu

Comment: Reply to rioV8 - I get the same command output using "Run-->Run Without Debugging" to execute the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to get rid of these executed scripts in TERMINAL. For clean output without these scripts, you can run in DEBUG CONSOLE.
Open the launch.json and change the value of console to **internalConsole**, like this:

> **"console": "internalConsole"**

Now there's no scripts before the output:

[image]

About how to generate a launch.json file with Python configurations, please refer to: [python-debug](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging).